# Table Footnote length problem

Tags: tables, footnotes

I don't understand why my table footnotes choose a certain length by itself and doesn't allow the text to go till the right margin of the page. There is no way to indent them with the left beginning of the table either.

[image]

```
\end{tabular}
\begin{tablenotes}\footnotesize
\item All results chosen here are on the Pareto Front in Figure~\ref{fig:ParetoSteffen}. 
\item Results labelled in letters A$\sim$J are from Table~\ref{table:StefResult} and are presented in bold font.
\end{tablenotes}
\end{table}
```

I don't want three rows below. I want one whole row. This table is rotated but I don't think this affects the matter.

[image]

```
\bottomrule[0.06em]
\end{tabular}
\begin{tablenotes}\footnotesize
\item All results chosen here are on the Pareto Front in Figure~\ref{fig:ParetoGenSteffen}. Results labelled in letters B$\sim$K are from Table~\ref{table:StefGenData} and are presented in bold font.
\end{tablenotes}
\end{table}
\end{landscape}
```

My last table is fine as below for no reason!

[image]

```
\bottomrule[0.06em]
\end{tabular}
\begin{tablenotes}[flushleft]\footnotesize
\item All results chosen here are on the Pareto Front in Figure~\ref{fig:ParetoTachi}. Results labelled in letters A$\sim$F are from Table~\ref{table:2TetraResult} and are presented in bold font.
\end{tablenotes}
\end{threeparttable}
\label{table:2TetraResultAppen}
\end{table}
\end{landscape}
```

edit:

```
\documentclass[a4paper,12pt,times,numbered,print,index]{Classes/PhDThesisPSnPDF}
\ifsetCustomMargin
  \RequirePackage[left=37mm,right=30mm,top=35mm,bottom=30mm]{geometry}
  \setFancyHdr % To apply fancy header after geometry package is loaded
\fi

\usepackage{threeparttable}
\usepackage{array}
\newcolumntype{+}{>{\global\let\currentrowstyle\relax}}
\newcolumntype{^}{>{\currentrowstyle}}
\newcommand{\rowstyle}[1]{\gdef\currentrowstyle{#1}#1\ignorespaces}

\usepackage[]{mcode}
\ifsetCustomFont

\RequirePackage[labelsep=space,tableposition=top]{caption}
\renewcommand{\figurename}{Fig.} %to support older versions of captions.sty
\usepackage{subcaption}

% ********************************** Tables ************************************
\usepackage{booktabs} % For professional looking tables
\usepackage{multirow}
\usepackage{listings}
\usepackage{color} %red, green, blue, yellow, cyan, magenta, black, white
\definecolor{mygreen}{RGB}{28,172,0} % color values Red, Green, Blue
\definecolor{mylilas}{RGB}{170,55,241}

% *********************************** SI Units *********************************
\usepackage{siunitx} % use this package module for SI units

\newenvironment{romanpages}{
  \setcounter{page}{1}
  \renewcommand{\thepage}{\roman{page}}}
{\newpage\renewcommand{\thepage}{\arabic{page}}}
% ******************************* Thesis Appendix B ********************************

\chapter{Data of Pareto optimised flexible polyhedra}
\sisetup{detect-all}
\begin{table}
\caption{Data of Pareto optimals of symmetrical Steffen flexible polyhedra}
\centering \label{table:StefResultAppen}
\begin{tabular}{+l^c^c^l^c^c^c^c^c^c}
\toprule[0.06em] 
& Result&\multicolumn{2}{c}{Objectives}&\multicolumn{5}{c}{Parameters} & \\
& Index&$\Theta$ & \multicolumn{1}{c}{$R$} & $a$ & $b$ & $c$ & $d$ & $e$ & \\ \midrule
\rowstyle{\bfseries}& B&\ang{52.5} & 0.013 & 5.5899 & 5.5464 & 0.1218 & 3.9489& 8.5 & \\
& 2&\ang{52.3} & 0.02  & 5.6033 & 5.5366 & 0.1871 & 4.0039& 8.5 & \\
& 3&\ang{52.0} & 0.03  & 5.6318 & 5.5308 & 0.2829 & 4.0878& 8.5 & \\
& 4&\ang{51.6} & 0.04  & 5.6517 & 5.5165 & 0.3793 & 4.1685& 8.5 & \\
\rowstyle{\bfseries}& C&\ang{51.2}& 0.05& 5.6666& 5.4959& 0.480& 4.2500& 8.5\\
& 5&\ang{50.8} & 0.06  & 5.6880 & 5.4828 & 0.5785 & 4.3314& 8.5 & \\
& 6&\ang{50.4} & 0.07  & 5.7097 & 5.4689 & 0.6792 & 4.4146& 8.5 & \\
& 7&\ang{49.9} & 0.08  & 5.7336 & 5.4554 & 0.7850 & 4.5020& 8.5 & \\
& 8&\ang{49.4} & 0.09  & 5.7647 & 5.4486 & 0.8893 & 4.5911& 8.5 & \\
\rowstyle{\bfseries}& D&\ang{48.8} & 0.1   & 5.7925 & 5.4370 & 0.9988 & 4.6816& 8.5\\
& 9 &\ang{48.2} & 0.11  & 5.7951 & 5.4053 & 1.1033 & 4.7562& 8.5 & \\
& 10&\ang{47.6} & 0.12  & 5.8162 & 5.3872 & 1.2155 & 4.8439& 8.5 & \\
& 11&\ang{47.0} & 0.1293& 5.8446 & 5.3757 & 1.3257 & 4.9330& 8.5 & \\
& 12&\ang{46.2} & 0.14  & 5.8486 & 5.3410 & 1.4451 & 5.0152& 8.5 & \\
& 13&\ang{45.4} & 0.15  & 5.8851 & 5.3316 & 1.5686 & 5.1149& 8.5 & \\
& 14&\ang{44.5} & 0.16  & 5.9069 & 5.3096 & 1.6929 & 5.2067& 8.5 & \\
\rowstyle{\bfseries}& E&\ang{44.6} & 0.17  & 6.5480 & 5.7564 & 1.8818 & 5.5754& 8.5\\
& 15&\ang{44.0} & 0.1785& 6.5513 & 5.7178 & 1.9933 & 5.6545& 8.5 & \\
& 16&\ang{41.4} & 0.18  & 7.9110 & 6.6602 & 2.3461 & 6.1127& 8.5 & \\
& 17&\ang{40.9} & 0.1904& 7.9907 & 6.6373 & 2.5317 & 6.2523& 8.5 & \\
\rowstyle{\bfseries}& F&\ang{40.5} & 0.2   & 8.0459 & 6.5934 & 2.7175 & 6.3879& 8.5\\
& 18&\ang{39.7} & 0.2091& 8.2124 & 6.6339 & 2.9133 & 6.5404& 8.5 & \\
\rowstyle{\bfseries}& A&\ang{27.4}& 0.2139& 6& 5& 2.5& 5.5 & 8.5 & \\
& 19&\ang{39.0} & 0.2205& 8.3712 & 6.6339 & 3.1730 & 6.7259& 8.5 & \\
& 20&\ang{38.2} & 0.2308& 8.3415 & 6.5354 & 3.3421 & 6.8473& 8.5 & \\
& 21&\ang{37.8} & 0.24  & 8.3858 & 6.4834 & 3.5275 & 6.9742& 8.5 & \\
\rowstyle{\bfseries}& G&\ang{37.0} & 0.25  & 8.5291 & 6.4675 & 3.7932 & 7.1545& 8.5\\
& 22&\ang{36.1} & 0.2627& 8.4623 & 6.3160 & 4.0191 & 7.2875& 8.5 & \\
& 23&\ang{35.6} & 0.27  & 8.3734 & 6.2074 & 4.1202 & 7.3392& 8.5 & \\
& 24&\ang{34.6} & 0.2789& 8.4971 & 6.1757 & 4.3896 & 7.5070& 8.5 & \\
& 25&\ang{34.0} & 0.284 & 8.3534 & 6.0600 & 4.4253 & 7.5107& 8.5 & \\
& 26&\ang{33.1} & 0.29  & 8.3444 & 6.0028 & 4.5518 & 7.5882& 8.5 & \\
\rowstyle{\bfseries}& H&\ang{31.8} & 0.3   & 8.4308 & 5.9183 & 4.8679 & 7.7451& 8.5\\
\rowstyle{\bfseries}& I&\ang{21.7} & 0.33  & 8.8174 & 5.7959 & 5.9376 & 8.4761& 8.5\\
\rowstyle{\bfseries}& J&\ang{10.4} & 0.34  & 8.1383 & 5.7008 & 5.5161 & 8.5020& 8.5\\
\bottomrule[0.06em]
\end{tabular}
\begin{tablenotes}[para]\footnotesize
\item All results chosen here are on the Pareto Front in Figure~\ref{fig:ParetoSteffen}. 
\item Results labelled in letters A$\sim$J are from Table~\ref{table:StefResult} and are presented in bold font.
\end{tablenotes}
\end{table}

\begin{landscape}
\begin{table}
\caption{Data of Pareto optimals of generalised Steffen flexible polyhedra}
\centering\label{table:StefGenDataAppen}
\begin{tabular}{+c^c^l^c^c^c^c^c^c^c^c^c^c}
\toprule[0.06em]
Index&$\Theta$&\multicolumn{1}{c|}{$R$}&$a_1$&$a_2$&$a_3$&$a_4$&$b_1$&$b_2$&$c_1$&$c_2$&$d$&$e$\\ \midrule
1&\ang{12.9}& 0.001& 5.8917& 5.4722& 10.1370& 9.3713& 9.2850& 5.4178& 1.0036& 0.0913& 5.8856& 8.5\\
2&\ang{53.1}& 0.009& 5.9480& 5.4139& 10.1791& 9.4598& 9.3032& 5.3384& 1.0637& 0.2212& 5.9105& 8.5\\
\rowstyle{\bfseries}B&\ang{58.9}& 0.0192& 5.9227& 5.4879& 10.0019& 9.5044& 9.2819& 5.3377& 0.9650& 0.3593& 6.2461& 8.5\\
\rowstyle{\bfseries}C&\ang{56.2}& 0.05& 6.02& 4.91& 10.36& 9.36& 8.67& 4.42& 2.46& 0.98& 6.55& 8.5\\
3&\ang{51.7}& 0.098& 6.4884& 7.6698& 7.4790& 6.3414& 6.6011& 6.7556& 1.3540& 1.3959& 9.4283& 8.5\\
4&\ang{50.5}& 0.12& 6.4685& 7.6568& 7.7282& 6.5150& 6.6675& 6.6311& 1.6560& 1.6267& 9.2408& 8.5\\
5&\ang{0}& 0.13& 8.7900& 8.0600& 8.0400& 8.7800& 5.8800& 5.8900& 6.0100& 6.0100& 8.5300& 8.5\\
6&\ang{49.6}& 0.136& 6& 6& 6& 6& 5& 5& 2.5& 2.5& 5.5& 8.5\\
\rowstyle{\bfseries}E&\ang{48.9}& 0.15& 6.5758& 7.6357& 7.6935& 6.6053& 6.5079& 6.4881& 1.9570& 1.9313& 8.6839& 8.5\\
\rowstyle{\bfseries}F&\ang{46.8}& 0.18& 6.6682& 7.7787& 7.6742& 6.6295& 6.3525& 6.3576& 2.3232& 2.3817& 8.4972& 8.5\\
7&\ang{45.4}& 0.19& 7.0737& 8.0746& 8.0935& 7.0823& 6.5396& 6.5335& 2.6379& 2.6289& 8.6351& 8.5\\
8&\ang{0}& 0.2& 6.58& 7.64& 7.69& 6.61& 6.51& 6.49& 1.96& 1.93& 8.68& 8.5\\
9&\ang{0}& 0.21& 8.98& 9.10& 9.11& 8.98& 5.85& 5.85& 5.96& 5.96& 8.46& 8.5\\
\rowstyle{\bfseries}G&\ang{43.6}& 0.213& 7.0674& 8.0777& 8.0787& 7.0675& 6.3761& 6.3777& 2.9517& 2.9505& 8.5583& 8.5\\
10&\ang{0}& 0.22& 7.07& 8.08& 8.08& 7.07& 6.38& 6.38& 2.95& 2.95& 8.56& 8.5\\
11&\ang{41.8}& 0.23& 6.9942& 8.0400& 8.0241& 6.9892& 6.2078& 6.2085& 3.2099& 3.2185& 8.5134& 8.5\\
12&\ang{39.1}& 0.25& 7.0497& 8.0988& 8.0872& 7.0442& 6.0672& 6.0748& 3.6012& 3.6055& 8.5370& 8.5\\
13&\ang{0}& 0.26& 6.58& 7.64& 7.69& 6.61& 6.51& 6.49& 1.96& 1.93& 8.68& 8.5\\
\rowstyle{\bfseries}H&\ang{36.7}& 0.27& 7.62& 8.39& 8.39& 7.62& 6.11& 6.12& 4.11& 4.11& 8.49& 8.5\\
14&\ang{0}& 0.28& 5.92& 5.49& 10.00& 9.50& 9.28& 5.34& 0.97& 0.36& 6.25& 8.5\\
15&\ang{0}& 0.29& 6& 6& 6& 6& 5& 5& 2.5& 2.5& 5.5& 8.5\\
16&\ang{31.5}& 0.3& 8.8476& 9.1462& 9.1398& 8.8477& 6.1690& 6.1683& 5.3087& 5.3122& 8.4926& 8.5\\
17&\ang{28.4}& 0.31& 6.02& 4.91& 10.36& 9.36& 8.67& 4.42& 2.46& 0.98& 6.55& 8.5\\
\rowstyle{\bfseries}I&\ang{26.9}& 0.32& 8.9643& 9.0803& 9.0768& 8.9654& 5.8469& 5.8462& 5.9439& 5.9467& 8.4391& 8.5\\
18&\ang{20.3}& 0.33& 6.33& 7.65& 7.73& 6.41& 6.79& 6.62& 1.45& 1.51& 9.64& 8.5\\
\rowstyle{\bfseries}J&\ang{10.2}& 0.34& 8.2205& 8.1707& 8.1688& 8.2168& 5.7152& 5.7163& 5.5713& 5.5706& 8.5019& 8.5\\
19&\ang{1.9}& 0.346& 8.79& 8.06& 8.04& 8.78& 5.88& 5.89& 6.01& 6.01& 8.53& 8.5\\
\rowstyle{\bfseries}K&\ang{0.6}& 0.348& 6.67& 7.78& 7.67& 6.63& 6.35& 6.36& 2.32& 2.38& 8.50& 8.5\\
\bottomrule[0.06em]
\end{tabular}
\begin{tablenotes}\footnotesize
\item All results chosen here are on the Pareto Front in Figure~\ref{fig:ParetoGenSteffen}. Results labelled in letters B$\sim$K are from Table~\ref{table:StefGenData} and are presented in bold font.
\end{tablenotes}
\end{table}
\end{landscape}

\begin{landscape}
\begin{table}\small
\caption{Data of Pareto optimals of two-tetrahedron flexible polyhedra}
\begin{threeparttable}
\begin{tabular}{+c^c^l^r^r^c^c^c^c^c^c^c^c^c^c^c}
\toprule[0.06em] 
$\Theta$ &&\multicolumn{1}{c}{$R$}&\multicolumn{1}{c}{$a$}&\multicolumn{1}{c}{$b_1$}& $b_2$ & $b_3$ & $b_4$&$c_1$&$c_2$&$c_3$& $c_4$&$d_1$&$d_2$&$e_1$&$e_2$\\ \midrule
\rowstyle{\bfseries}A&\ang{79.4}& 0.016& 10.5575& 6.8962& 7.2996& 6.9266& 7.2709& 7.2757& 6.8598& 7.1846& 6.8196& 0.1728& 0.2493& 7.5& 7.5535\\
1&\ang{73.9}& 0.04& 10.1& 8.7& 7.5& 7.0& 7.9& 7.1& 7.8& 8.8& 7.3& 3.3& 3.3& 7.5& 8.1\\
2&\ang{74.6}& 0.05& 10.9& 7.8& 7.7& 7.7& 7.7& 7.9& 7.5& 7.9& 7.4& 2.2& 2.2& 7.5& 8.1\\
3&\ang{70.2}& 0.07& 10.2& 10.0& 7.9& 6.8& 7.7& 7.0& 7.9& 9.9& 7.7& 5.4& 5.6& 7.5& 8.2\\
4&\ang{60.8}& 0.09& 10.6& 6.9& 7.3& 6.9& 7.3& 7.3& 6.9& 7.2& 6.8& 0.2& 0.3& 7.5& 7.6\\
\rowstyle{\bfseries}B&\ang{69.2}& 0.1& 9.9& 7.0& 7.2& 7.0& 7.2& 7.2& 6.8& 7.2& 6.8& 1.1& 1.2& 7.5& 7.9\\
5&\ang{61.4}& 0.12& 10.9& 7.8& 7.7& 7.7& 7.7& 7.9& 7.5& 7.9& 7.4& 2.2& 2.2& 7.5& 8.1\\
6&\ang{65.3}& 0.14& 10.2& 10.0& 7.9& 6.8& 7.7& 7.0& 7.9& 9.9& 7.7& 5.4& 5.6& 7.5& 8.2\\
7&\ang{64.3}& 0.15& 9.8& 9.3& 7.6& 6.0& 6.2& 6.1& 6.4& 9.4& 7.6& 6.8& 7.0& 7.5& 7.6\\
\rowstyle{\bfseries}C&\ang{61.5}& 0.17& 10.7611& 7.8164& 7.7626& 7.6931& 7.7447& 7.8923& 7.4600& 7.9165& 7.4135& 2.1408& 2.1326& 7.5& 8.0839\\
8&\ang{61.7}& 0.18& 10.9& 7.8& 7.7& 7.7& 7.7& 7.9& 7.5& 7.9& 7.4& 2.2& 2.2& 7.5& 8.1\\
9&\ang{60.6}& 0.19& 10.1& 8.7& 7.5& 7.0& 7.9& 7.1& 7.8& 8.8& 7.3& 3.3& 3.3& 7.5& 8.1\\
10&\ang{59.6}& 0.2& 10.2& 10.0& 7.9& 6.8& 7.7& 7.0& 7.9& 9.9& 7.7& 5.4& 5.6& 7.5& 8.2\\
11&\ang{58.5}& 0.21& 9.8& 9.3& 7.6& 6.0& 6.2& 6.1& 6.4& 9.4& 7.6& 6.8& 7.0& 7.5& 7.6\\
12&\ang{56.6}& 0.22& 9.9& 7.0& 7.2& 7.0& 7.2& 7.2& 6.8& 7.2& 6.8& 1.1& 1.2& 7.5& 7.9\\
13&\ang{56.1}& 0.23& 10.9& 7.8& 7.7& 7.7& 7.7& 7.9& 7.5& 7.9& 7.4& 2.2& 2.2& 7.5& 8.1\\
14&\ang{54.9}& 0.24& 10.1& 8.7& 7.5& 7.0& 7.9& 7.1& 7.8& 8.8& 7.3& 3.3& 3.3& 7.5& 8.1\\
\rowstyle{\bfseries}D&\ang{53.1}& 0.25& 10.2& 10.0& 7.9& 6.8& 7.7& 7.0& 7.9& 9.9& 7.7& 5.4& 5.6& 7.5& 8.2\\
15&\ang{51.7}& 0.26& 9.8& 9.3& 7.6& 6.0& 6.2& 6.1& 6.4& 9.4& 7.6& 6.8& 7.0& 7.5& 7.6\\
16&\ang{50.4}& 0.27& 10.6& 6.9& 7.3& 6.9& 7.3& 7.3& 6.9& 7.2& 6.8& 0.2& 0.3& 7.5& 7.6\\
17&\ang{48.1}& 0.28& 9.9& 7.0& 7.2& 7.0& 7.2& 7.2& 6.8& 7.2& 6.8& 1.1& 1.2& 7.5& 7.9\\
18&\ang{45.3}& 0.3& 10.0765& 9.1387& 7.5620& 6.9263& 7.7037& 6.9299& 7.7408& 9.0451& 7.3500& 4.2529& 4.2287& 7.5& 8.0301\\
19&\ang{41.9}& 0.32& 9.8& 9.3& 7.6& 6.0& 6.2& 6.1& 6.4& 9.4& 7.6& 6.8& 7.0& 7.5& 7.6\\
\rowstyle{\bfseries}E&\ang{36.0}& 0.34& 10.2& 10.0& 7.9& 6.8& 7.7& 7.0& 7.9& 9.9& 7.7& 5.4& 5.6& 7.5& 8.2\\
20&\ang{33.7}& 0.35& 9.8& 9.3& 7.6& 6.0& 6.2& 6.1& 6.4& 9.4& 7.6& 6.8& 7.0& 7.5& 7.6\\
21&\ang{30.1}& 0.36& 9.8& 9.3& 7.6& 6.0& 6.2& 6.1& 6.4& 9.4& 7.6& 6.8& 7.0& 7.5& 7.6\\
22&\ang{24.1}& 0.37& 9.8& 9.3& 7.6& 6.0& 6.2& 6.1& 6.4& 9.4& 7.6& 6.8& 7.0& 7.5& 7.6\\
\rowstyle{\bfseries}F&\ang{18.9}& 0.38& 9.8248& 9.3041& 7.6191& 6.0042& 6.2360& 6.1191& 6.3792& 9.3612& 7.5745& 6.7780& 6.9647& 7.5& 7.5570\\
\bottomrule[0.06em]
\end{tabular}
\begin{tablenotes}[flushleft]\footnotesize
\item All results chosen here are on the Pareto Front in Figure~\ref{fig:ParetoTachi}. Results labelled in letters A$\sim$F are from Table~\ref{table:2TetraResult} and are presented in bold font.
\end{tablenotes}
\end{threeparttable}
\label{table:2TetraResultAppen}
\end{table}
\end{landscape}

\end{document}
```

Comment: please provide complete small document beginning with `\documentclass{...}` followed by necessary packages, `\begin{document}` table and ending with `\end{document}` which reproduce your problem. welcome to tex.se!

Comment: @Bobyandbob: Not necessarily: there's the `para` option of `threeparttable`.

Comment: [para] doesn't change my problem at all. I don't understand why my table 3 worked with exactly the same code as for table 1 and 2, which don't work.

Comment: @Bobyandbob I do want tow rows in the first table, but it produces three rows in the midde.  I want one row in the second table, but it produces three rows again. I just no way make it go till the end. Something specified the length of the footnotes of these two tables strangely.

Comment: Plesse add a full minimal working example. Please read the links about MWE carefully. We dont know Classes/PhDThesisPSnPDF! Its hard to help you , with a good MWE its easier for everyone.

Comment: @Bobyandbob  I'm a beginner. I'm just using the uni template. What is mwe? Does it stand for sth? Do I have to change it to \documentclass{article}? Will this change the whole problem?

Comment: No problem. Yes if you could reproduce the error with article it would help. Have a look to minimal working example [MWE](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/228/ive-just-been-asked-to-write-a-minimal-example-what-is-that). I'm sure that we will solve your problem. You are welcome.

Comment: thank you for provided *mwe* (minimal working example). unfortunately it is not complete (missing are packages, `\begin{document}` and used are some proprietary
 packages which we haven't. short inspection of your tables shows, that its code is terrible mess which cause your problems. i would not use your way how you made some row font boldface and reconsider how to design your tables.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

after your edit of question it become actually new question: *how to set table properly* ... hence new answer.

you have problems with design of your table, not with `tablenotes`. it works properly only in `threeparttable` environments and not with `tabular` as you used them. below is *mwe* based on yours, in which i consider/change the following:

- all table are strict in `threeparttable` environment
- for all columns except the first one are used `S` column type
- concept for rows determining boldface fonts is replaced with individulay determined boldface for each cell
- number defined columns are equal to number used columns
- last table, which slightly to big, is reduced `\tabcolsep`
- table are already in editor set so, that columns are obvious
- from your tables i consider only the first few rows, others is easy to adopt to proposed solution
  in preamble are considered only packages needed for proposed table settings.

```
\documentclass[a4paper]{book}

\usepackage{array, booktabs, multirow, threeparttable}
\usepackage[labelsep=space,tableposition=top]{caption}

\usepackage{siunitx} % use this package module for SI units
\usepackage{etoolbox}                       % <-- new
\newcommand{\BF}{\fontseries{b}\selectfont} % <--
\robustify\BF                               % <--

\usepackage{pdflscape}

\begin{document}
    \begin{table}
\caption{Data of Pareto optimals of symmetrical Steffen flexible polyhedra}
\label{table:StefResultAppen}
    \centering
\begin{threeparttable}
\begin{tabular}{c     S[detect-weight,
                       mode=text,
                       table-format=2.1]<{$^\circ$}
                *{5}{S[detect-weight,
                       mode=text,
                       table-format=1.4]}
                     S[detect-weight,
                       mode=text,
                       table-format=1.1]
                }
    \toprule
Result      &   \multicolumn{2}{c}{Objectives}
                                        &   \multicolumn{5}{c}{Parameters}      \\
    \cmidrule(lr){2-3}
    \cmidrule(lr){4-8}
Index       & $\Theta$   & {$R$}        & {$a$}         & {$b$}
                         & {$c$}        & {$d$}         & {$e$}                 \\
    \midrule
\textbf{B}  &\BF 52.5   & \BF 0.013    & \BF 5.5899    & \BF 5.5464
                        & \BF 0.1218   & \BF 3.9489    & \BF 8.5                                              \\
2           & 52.3      & 0.02  & 5.6033 & 5.5366 & 0.1871 & 4.0039    & 8.5   \\
3           & 52.0      & 0.03  & 5.6318 & 5.5308 & 0.2829 & 4.0878    & 8.5   \\
4           & 51.6      & 0.04  & 5.6517 & 5.5165 & 0.3793 & 4.1685    & 8.5   \\
\textbf{C}  &\BF 51.2   & \BF 0.05     & \BF 5.6666    & \BF 5.4959
                        & \BF 0.480    & \BF 4.2500    & \BF 8.5               \\
    \bottomrule
\end{tabular}
\begin{tablenotes}[para]\footnotesize
\item All results chosen here are on the Pareto Front in Figure~\ref{fig:ParetoSteffen}.
\item Results labelled in letters A$\sim$J are from Table~\ref{table:StefResult} and are presented in bold font.
\end{tablenotes}
\end{threeparttable}
\end{table}

\begin{landscape}
\begin{threeparttable}
\caption{Data of Pareto optimals of generalised Steffen flexible polyhedra}
\centering\label{table:StefGenDataAppen}
\begin{tabular}{c    S[detect-weight,
                       mode=text,
                       table-format=2.1]<{$^\circ$}
               *{10}{S[detect-weight,
                       mode=text,
                       table-format=1.4]}
                     S[detect-weight,
                       mode=text,
                       table-format=1.1]
                }
\toprule[0.06em]
Index   & $\Theta$  & \multicolumn{1}{c|}{$R$}
        & {$a_1$}   & {$a_2$}   & {$a_3$}   & {$a_4$}
        & {$b_1$}   & {$b_2$}   & {$c_1$}   & {$c_2$}
        & {$d$}     & {$e$}                                 \\
        \midrule
1           & 12.9  & 0.001     & 5.8917    & 5.4722    & 10.1370
                    & 9.3713    & 9.2850    & 5.4178    & 1.0036
                    & 0.0913    & 5.8856    & 8.5           \\
2           & 53.1  & 0.009     & 5.9480    & 5.4139    & 10.1791
                    & 9.4598    & 9.3032    & 5.3384    & 1.0637
                    & 0.2212    & 5.9105    & 8.5           \\
\textbf{B}  &\BF 58.9
                    &\BF 0.0192 &\BF 5.9227 &\BF 5.4879 &\BF 10.0019
                    &\BF 9.5044 &\BF 9.2819 &\BF 5.3377 &\BF 0.9650
                    &\BF 0.3593 &\BF 6.2461 &\BF 8.5        \\
\textbf{C}  & 56.2  &\BF 0.05   &\BF 6.02   &\BF 4.91   &\BF 10.36
                    &\BF 9.36   &\BF 8.67   &\BF 4.42   &\BF 2.46
                    &\BF 0.98   &\BF 6.55   &\BF 8.5        \\
3           & 51.7  & 0.098     & 6.4884    & 7.6698    & 7.4790
                    & 6.3414    & 6.6011    & 6.7556    & 1.3540
                    & 1.3959    & 9.4283    & 8.5           \\
4           & 50.5  & 0.12      & 6.4685    & 7.6568    & 7.7282
                    & 6.5150    & 6.6675    & 6.6311    & 1.6560
                    & 1.6267    & 9.2408    & 8.5           \\
5           & 0     & 0.13      & 8.7900    & 8.0600    & 8.0400
                    & 8.7800    & 5.8800    & 5.8900    & 6.0100
                    & 6.0100    & 8.5300    & 8.5           \\
6           & 49.6  & 0.136     & 6         & 6         & 6
                    & 6         & 5         & 5         & 2.5
                    & 2.5       & 5.5       & 8.5           \\
\textbf{E}  &\BF 48.9
                    &\BF 0.15   &\BF 6.5758 &\BF 7.6357 &\BF 7.6935
                    &\BF 6.6053 &\BF 6.5079 &\BF 6.4881 &\BF 1.9570
                    &\BF 1.9313 &\BF 8.6839 &\BF 8.5        \\
    \bottomrule
\end{tabular}
\begin{tablenotes}\footnotesize
\item All results chosen here are on the Pareto Front in Figure~\ref{fig:ParetoGenSteffen}. Results labelled in letters B$\sim$K are from Table~\ref{table:StefGenData} and are presented in bold font.
\end{tablenotes}
\end{threeparttable}
\end{landscape}

\begin{landscape}
    \small
    \setlength\tabcolsep{0pt}
\begin{threeparttable}
\caption{Data of Pareto optimals of two-tetrahedron flexible polyhedra}
\begin{tabular*}{\linewidth}{@{\extracolsep{\fill}}
                 c  S[detect-weight,
                      mode=text,
                      table-format=2.1]<{$^\circ$}
              *{12}{S[detect-weight,
                      mode=text,
                      table-format=1.4]}
                    S[detect-weight,
                      mode=text,
                      table-format=1.1]
                    S[detect-weight,
                      mode=text,
                      table-format=1.4]
                }
    \toprule
$\Theta$    & {$R$}     & {$a$}     & {$b_1$}   & {$b_2$}   & {$b_3$}
                        & {$b_4$}   & {$c_1$}   & {$c_2$}   & {$c_3$}
                        & {$c_4$}   & {$d_1$}   & {$d_2$}   & {$e_1$}
                        & {$e_2$}   &   ?                               \\
    \midrule
\textbf{A}  &\BF 79.4   &\BF 0.016  &\BF 10.5575&\BF 6.8962 &\BF 7.2996
                        &\BF 6.9266 &\BF 7.2709 &\BF 7.2757 &\BF 6.8598
                        &\BF 7.1846 &\BF 6.8196 &\BF 0.1728 &\BF 0.2493
                        &\BF 7.5    &\BF 7.5535                         \\
1           & 73.9      & 0.04      & 10.1      & 8.7       & 7.5
            & 7.0       & 7.9       & 7.1       & 7.8
            & 8.8       & 7.3       & 3.3       & 3.3
            & 7.5       & 8.1                               \\
2           & 74.6      & 0.05      & 10.9      & 7.8       & 7.7
            & 7.7       & 7.7       & 7.9       & 7.5
            & 7.9       & 7.4       & 2.2       & 2.2
            & 7.5       & 8.1                               \\
3           & 70.2      & 0.07      & 10.2      & 10.0      & 7.9
            & 6.8       & 7.7       & 7.0       & 7.9
            & 9.9       & 7.7       & 5.4       & 5.6
            & 7.5       & 8.2                               \\
4           & 60.8      & 0.09      & 10.6      & 6.9       & 7.3
            & 6.9       & 7.3       & 7.3       & 6.9
            & 7.2       & 6.8       & 0.2       & 0.3
            & 7.5       & 7.6                               \\
\textbf{B}  &\BF 69.2   &\BF 0.1    &\BF 9.9    &\BF 7.0    &\BF 7.2
                        &\BF 7.0    &\BF 7.2    &\BF 7.2    &\BF 6.8
                        &\BF 7.2    &\BF 6.8    &\BF 1.1    &\BF  1.2
                        &\BF 7.5    &\BF 7.9\\
    \bottomrule
\end{tabular*}
\begin{tablenotes}[flushleft]\footnotesize
\item All results chosen here are on the Pareto Front in Figure~\ref{fig:ParetoTachi}. Results labelled in letters A$\sim$F are from Table~\ref{table:2TetraResult} and are presented in bold font.
\end{tablenotes}
\end{threeparttable}
\label{table:2TetraResultAppen}
\end{landscape}
\end{document}
```

[image]

[image]

[image]

Now `tablenotes` appear as i show in the first answer.

Comment: Thank you soooo much! From looking at your table, I suddenly realised why my third table worked and the first two didn't: because I didn't use threeparttable for the first two and I did for the third one! Thank you so much for your examples! Your  threeparttable really helped!

Answer (score 2):

your table notes are exactly what you require. to emphasize this i wrote the following *mwe* with three scenarios of `tablenotes` use:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{pdflscape}
\usepackage{threeparttable}
\usepackage{lipsum}

\begin{document}
\begin{landscape}
\begin{threeparttable}
\caption{my wide table}
\begin{tabular*}{\linewidth}{*{2}{p{\dimexpr0.5\linewidth-2\tabcolsep}}}
\lipsum*[11]       &   \lipsum*[11] \\
    \hline
\end{tabular*}
\begin{tablenotes}\footnotesize           % <--- first case
\item[\textbullet] All results chosen here are on the Pareto Front in Figure~\ref{fig:ParetoSteffen}.
\item[\textbullet] Results labelled in letters A$\sim$J are from Table~\ref{table:StefResult} and are presented in bold font.
\item[\textbullet] \lipsum*[11]
\end{tablenotes}
\medskip
\begin{tablenotes}[para]\footnotesize     % <--- second case
\item[\textbullet] All results chosen here are on the Pareto Front in Figure~\ref{fig:ParetoSteffen}.
\item[\textbullet] Results labelled in letters A$\sim$J are from Table~\ref{table:StefResult} and are presented in bold font.
\item[\textbullet] \lipsum*[11]
\end{tablenotes}
\medskip
\begin{tablenotes}[para]\footnotesize     % <--- third case
\item   All results chosen here are on the Pareto Front in Figure~\ref{fig:ParetoSteffen}.
\item   Results labelled in letters A$\sim$J are from Table~\ref{table:StefResult} and are presented in bold font.
\item   \lipsum*[11]
\end{tablenotes}
\end{threeparttable}
\end{landscape}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Thank you. It seams in all three cases, your texts go through the whole line. But my table 1 and 2 don't allow this to happen, and table 3 for no reason does with the same code!!

Comment: then you have something what is not considered in my *mwe*. if you will not provide a small, complete document, like mine in answer, which will demonstrate your problem, we can't help you. sorry, but my crystal ball is temporary busy with other tasks :-(, so i cant see, what is going-on in your document.